# Using nawk, how to print the first names for all those in the 916 area code?

Tags: linux, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using nawk, how to print all first names containing four characters?](https://superuser.com/questions/489058/using-nawk-how-to-print-all-first-names-containing-four-characters)

Using nawk, how to print the first names for all those in the 916 area code?
I've tried nawk ‘$3 ~ /(916)/{print $1}’ inputfile but didn' work.

Jody Savage:(206) 548-1278:15:188:150

Guy Quigley:(916) 343-6410:250:100:175

Dan Savage:(406) 298-7744:450:300:275

Nancy McNeil:(206) 548-1278:250:80:75

John Goldenrod:(916) 348-4278:250:100:175

Chet Main:(510) 548-5258:50:95:135

Comment: I really hope these are not real phone numbers and the real names of these people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
nawk '$2 ~ "(916)" {print}' file.txt
```

Comment: You should "accept" the question then =)  (Dunno if it's possible with a closed question)